# Facing a 502 error message during deployment of nginx on an EC2 instance in the AWS cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, terraform

I created 2 files: main.tf and compute.tf. The main file contains all the necessary information, like VPC, Public subnet 1, Public subnet 2, Internet Gateway,  Assosiate public subnet with route table,  Load balancer,  Load Balancer listener,  Target group,  Security Group, Load balancer security group. Each resource creates a work. The main.tf file looks following:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main_vpc" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"

  tags = {
    Name = "main_vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_1" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "eu-west-1a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet_1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_2" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "eu-west-1b"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet_2"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "internet_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "internet_gateway"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.internet_gateway.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "route_table"
  }
}

# Assosiate public subnet with route table
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_subnet_1_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route_table.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_subnet_2_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet_2.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route_table.id
}

# Create Load balancer
resource "aws_lb" "two-tier-lb" {
  name               = "two-tier-lb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.two-tier-alb-sg.id]
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id, aws_subnet.public_subnet_2.id]

  tags = {
    Environment = "two-tier-lb"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "two-tier-lb-tg" {
  name     = "two-tier-lb-tg"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
}

# Create Load Balancer listener
resource "aws_lb_listener" "two-tier-lb-listner" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.two-tier-lb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.two-tier-lb-tg.arn
  }
}

# Create Target group
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "two-tier-loadb_target" {
  name       = "target"
  depends_on = [aws_vpc.main_vpc]
  port       = "80"
  protocol   = "HTTP"
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id

}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "two-tier-tg-attch-1" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.two-tier-loadb_target.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.two-tier-web-server-1.id
  port             = 80
}
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "two-tier-tg-attch-2" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.two-tier-loadb_target.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.two-tier-web-server-2.id
  port             = 80
}

# Security Group
resource "aws_security_group" "two-tier-ec2-sg" {
  name        = "two-tier-ec2-sg"
  description = "Allow traffic from VPC"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.main_vpc
  ]

  ingress {
    from_port = "0"
    to_port   = "0"
    protocol  = "-1"
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = "80"
    to_port     = "80"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = "22"
    to_port     = "22"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = "0"
    to_port     = "0"
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "two-tier-ec2-sg"
  }
}

# Load balancer security group
resource "aws_security_group" "two-tier-alb-sg" {
  name        = "two-tier-alb-sg"
  description = "load balancer security group"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.main_vpc
  ]


  ingress {
    from_port   = "0"
    to_port     = "0"
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = "0"
    to_port     = "0"
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }


  tags = {
    Name = "two-tier-alb-sg"
  }
}
```

I create two EC2 instances and install Nginx on them. I created aws_eip for both EC2 instances. After that, I created an aws_key_pair. I tried to run the whole code without the aws_key_pair, but the result was the same. The compute.tf file looks following:

```
# Public subnet EC2 instance 1
resource "aws_instance" "two-tier-web-server-1" {
  ami             = "ami-0f3164307ee5d695a"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.two-tier-ec2-sg.id]
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id
  key_name        = aws_key_pair.key-tf.id

  tags = {
    Name = "two-tier-web-server-1"
  }

  user_data = <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1 -y 
sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
EOF
}

# Public subnet  EC2 instance 2
resource "aws_instance" "two-tier-web-server-2" {
  ami             = "ami-0f3164307ee5d695a"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.two-tier-ec2-sg.id]
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.public_subnet_2.id
  key_name        = aws_key_pair.key-tf.id

  tags = {
    Name = "two-tier-web-server-2"
  }

  user_data = <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1 -y 
sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
EOF
}

#EIP

resource "aws_eip" "two-tier-web-server-1-eip" {
  vpc = true

  instance   = aws_instance.two-tier-web-server-1.id
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.internet_gateway]
}

resource "aws_eip" "two-tier-web-server-2-eip" {
  vpc = true

  instance   = aws_instance.two-tier-web-server-2.id
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.internet_gateway]
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "key-tf" {
  key_name   = "key-tf"
  public_key = file("/Users/roman/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
}
```

[image: EC2 instances in details]

When I try to visit the public IP address it showed me "This site can’t be reached 54.155.189.11 took too long to respond."

Comment: Did you login to the EC2 instance and verify nginx is running? Also, your GitHub link doesn't work, and you should include the Terraform code in the question itself anyway.

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: Did you login to the EC2 instance and verify nginx is running?

Comment: And when I said include the code in your question, I meant all the relevant terraform code. Without seeing your load balancer, target group, and relevant security groups, there is not enough information in your question for anyone to help.

Comment: Finally updated the core code, the provider.tf is not needed as the terraform creates the infrastructure as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the AMI that I used. The script for installing the Nginx server on the Amazon Linux 2023 AMI should look like this:

```
sudo dnf update
sudo dnf install -y nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx.service
sudo systemctl status nginx.service
sudo systemctl enable nginx.service
```